# Zend_Form_Element_File returns false on validation when not required

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a Zend Form containing one file element amongst others.

```
    $this->addElement('file', 'image', array(
        'label'         => 'Upload Image:',
        'destination'   => APPLICATION_PATH . '/tmp/',
        'validators'    => array(
            array('count', true, array(
                'min'   => 1,
                'max'   => 1,
                'messages'  => array(
                    Zend_Validate_File_Count::TOO_FEW =>
                        'You must upload an image file',
                    Zend_Validate_File_Count::TOO_MANY =>
                        'You can only upload one image file'))),
            array('extension', true, array(
                'extention' => 'jpg,png,gif',
                'messages'  => array(
                    Zend_Validate_File_Extension::NOT_FOUND =>
                        'The file has an invalid extention (jpg,png,gif only)',
                    Zend_Validate_File_Extension::FALSE_EXTENSION =>
                        'The file has an invalid extention (jpg,png,gif only)'))),
            array('imageSize', true, array(
                'minheight' => self::IMAGEHEIGHT,
                'minwidth'  => self::IMAGEWIDTH,
                'maxheight' => self::IMAGEHEIGHT,
                'maxwidth'  => self::IMAGEWIDTH,
                'messages'  => array(
                    Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::HEIGHT_TOO_BIG =>
                        'The image must be exactly ' . self::IMAGEHEIGHT . ' pixels tall',
                    Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::HEIGHT_TOO_SMALL =>
                        'The image must be exactly ' . self::IMAGEHEIGHT . ' pixels tall',
                    Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::WIDTH_TOO_BIG =>
                        'The image must be exactly ' . self::IMAGEWIDTH . ' pixels wide',
                    Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::WIDTH_TOO_SMALL =>
                        'The image must be exactly ' . self::IMAGEWIDTH . ' pixels wide',
                    Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::NOT_DETECTED =>
                        'The image dimensions cannot be detected',
                    Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::NOT_READABLE =>
                        'The image dimensions cannot be read'))))
    ));
```

This file element is set to not required in a later piece of code. When I submit the form without a file attached the form validtion returns false, also when I look for the form errors with the getErrors() method no errors are reported.  If I submit the form with an attachment everything works fine.

I have been googleing this for sometime but cannot find an answer.  I hope that someone can shed some light as to why this is happening, I'm using ZF 1.11.11.

Thanks in advance.

Garry

**EDIT**

Here are some more code samples as requested.

These are the methods I use to validate the forms. I have marked the code I use as a workaround for the validation bug.

```
public function formValid(Array $params)
{
    if (is_null($this->_form))
        throw new Zend_Exception('You must first initialize the form');

    $formValid = $this->_validateForm($this->_form, $params);

    // Workaround for bug in validating file elements
    if (!$formValid) {
        if (!$this->_form->getMessages()) {
            $formValid = true;
            $this->_validValues = $this->_form->getValidValues($params);
        }
    }

    if ($formValid) {
        if ($this->_form instanceof Admin_Form_AddDirectSite || 
            $this->_form instanceof Admin_Form_EditDirectSite) {
                if (isset($this->_validValues['replaceImage'])) {
                    return $this->_form->getElement('image')->receive();
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } elseif ($this->_form instanceof Admin_Form_PromoteDirectSite) {
                $today = new Zend_Date();
                $expires = new zend_date($this->_validValues['DirectSitesHighlighted']['toDate']);
                if ($expires->isEarlier($today)) {
                    $this->_form->getSubForm('DirectSitesHighlighted')
                                ->getElement('toDate')
                                ->addError('The date must be in the future');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

protected function _validateForm(Zend_Form $form, Array $params)
{
    if ($form->isValid($params)) {
        $this->_validValues = $form->getValidValues($params);
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->_validValues = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

These are the functions I use to initialize the forms, there are two form classes sharing one abstract class.

```
public function initAddForm() 
{
    $this->_form = new Admin_Form_AddDirectSite();
    return $this;
}

public function initEditForm() 
{
    $this->_form = new Admin_Form_EditDirectSite();
    return $this;
}
```

And these are the three form classes.

```
class Admin_Form_AddDirectSite extends Admin_Form_DirectSites_Abstract
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->setAction('/admin/direct-sites/add');

        $this->setDecorators(array(
            array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'forms/addDirectSites.phtml'))
        ));

        $this->getElement('image')->setRequired(true);

        $this->addElement('hidden', 'replaceImage', array(
            'required'      => true,
            'label'         => 'Replace Image:',
            'value'         => 1,
            'filters'       => array('Int'),
        ));
    }
}

class Admin_Form_EditDirectSite extends Admin_Form_DirectSites_Abstract
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->setAction('/admin/direct-sites/edit');

        $this->setDecorators(array(
            array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'forms/editDirectSites.phtml'))
        ));

        $this->getElement('image')->setRequired(false);

        $this->addElement('checkbox', 'replaceImage', array(
            'required'      => false,
            'label'         => 'Replace Image:',
            'checked'       => false,
            'attribs'       => array(
                'title'         => 'Click to replace the image file'
            ),
            'filters'       => array('Int'),
            'validators'    => array(
                array('Int', true, array(
                    'messages'  => array(
                        Zend_Validate_Int::NOT_INT =>
                            'You must check to replace the image file'))))
        ));

        $this->addElement('hidden', 'directSiteId', array(
            'required'  => false,
            'vslue'     => null
        ));
    }
}

abstract class Admin_Form_DirectSites_Abstract extends Freedom_Zend_Form
{
    /**
     * Domain prefix http://www.
     * @var integer
     */
    const HTTPWWW = 1;

    /**
     * Domain prefix http://
     * @var integer
     */
    const HTTP = 2;

    /**
     * The image width in pixels
     * @var integer
     */
    const IMAGEWIDTH = 100;

    /**
     * The image height in pixels
     * @var integer
     */
    const IMAGEHEIGHT = 100;

    /**
     * Initialize the form
     * @see Zend_Form::init()
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $domainPrefix = array(
            self::HTTPWWW   => 'http://www.',
            self::HTTP      => 'http;//'
        );

        $genres = Model_Doctrine_GenresTable::getInstance()->getAllKeyPairs();

        $artworkMediums = Model_Doctrine_ArtworkMediumsTable::getInstance()->getAllKeyPairs();

        $this->setName('directSitesForm') // setup registration form
             ->setAttrib('id', 'directSitesForm')
             ->setMethod('post')
             ->setAttrib('class', 'directSitesForm')
             ->setEnctype(Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);

        $this->addElementPrefixPath('Freedom_Zend', 'Freedom/Zend'); // add element prefix path
        $this->addPrefixPath('Freedom_Zend_Form', 'Freedom/Zend/Form'); // add form prefix path

        $directSitesDescription = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
        $directSitesTitle = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

        $this->addElement('text', 'domainName', array(
            'required'  => true,
            'label'     => 'Domain Name:',
            'attribs'   => array(
                'title'     => 'Please enter the url of the site',
                'size'      => 20,
                'maxlength' => 255
            ),
            'filters'       => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags', 'StripNewlines'),
            'validators'    => array(
                array('NotEmpty', true, array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY =>
                                "You must specify the domain name"))),
                array('StringLength', true, array(
                        'min'   => 5,
                        'max' => 255,
                        'messages'  => array(
                            Zend_Validate_StringLength::INVALID =>
                                'Your URL must be between 5 and 255 characters in length',
                            Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_LONG =>
                                'Your URL must not contain more than 255 characters',
                            Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT =>
                                'Your URL must contain more than 5 characters'))))
        ));

        $this->addElement('radio', 'websitePrefix', array(
            'required'  => true,
            'label'     => 'Domain Prefix:',
            'attribs'   => array(
                'title'     => 'Please select the URL prefix for the domain name'
            ),
            'multiOptions'  => $domainPrefix,
            'value'     => self::HTTPWWW,
            'filters' => array('int'),
            'validators' => array(
                array('NotEmpty', true, array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY =>
                            "You must select your agency's website URL",
                        Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::INVALID =>
                            "You must select your agency's website URL"))),
                array('InArray', true, array(
                    'haystack'  => array_keys($domainPrefix),
                    'messages' => array(
                        Zend_Validate_InArray::NOT_IN_ARRAY =>
                            "You must select your agency's website URL"))))
        ));

        $directSitesTitle->addElement('text', 'title', array(
            'required'  => true,
            'label'     => 'Title:',
            'attribs'   => array(
                'title'     => 'Please enter the name of the site',
                'size'      => 20,
                'maxlength' => 255
            ),
            'filters'       => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags', 'StripNewlines'),
            'validators'    => array(
                array('NotEmpty', true, array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY =>
                                "You must specify the sites title"))),
                array('StringLength', true, array(
                        'min'   => 5,
                        'max' => 100,
                        'messages'  => array(
                            Zend_Validate_StringLength::INVALID =>
                                'Your title must be between 5 and 100 characters in length',
                            Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_LONG =>
                                'Your title must not contain more than 100 characters',
                            Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT =>
                                'Your title must contain more than 5 characters'))))
        ));

        $directSitesDescription->addElement('text', 'description', array(
            'required'  => true,
            'label'     => 'Description:',
            'attribs'   => array(
                'title'     => 'Please enter the description of the site',
                'size'      => 50,
                'maxlength' => 100
            ),
            'filters'       => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags', 'StripNewlines'),
            'validators'    => array(
                array('NotEmpty', true, array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY =>
                                "You must specify the sites description"))),
                array('StringLength', true, array(
                        'min'   => 5,
                        'max' => 100,
                        'messages'  => array(
                            Zend_Validate_StringLength::INVALID =>
                                'Your sites description must be between 5 and 100 characters in length',
                            Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_LONG =>
                                'Your sites description must not contain more than 100 characters',
                            Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT =>
                                'Your sites description must contain more than 5 characters'))))
        ));

        $this->addElement('file', 'image', array(
            'label'         => 'Upload Image:',
            'destination'   => APPLICATION_PATH . '/tmp/',
            'validators'    => array(
                array('count', true, array(
                    'min'   => 0,
                    'max'   => 1,
                    'messages'  => array(
                        Zend_Validate_File_Count::TOO_FEW =>
                            'You must upload an image file',
                        Zend_Validate_File_Count::TOO_MANY =>
                            'You can only upload one image file'))),
                array('extension', true, array(
                    'extention' => 'jpg,png,gif',
                    'messages'  => array(
                        Zend_Validate_File_Extension::NOT_FOUND =>
                            'The file has an invalid extention (jpg,png,gif only)',
                        Zend_Validate_File_Extension::FALSE_EXTENSION =>
                            'The file has an invalid extention (jpg,png,gif only)'))),
                array('imageSize', true, array(
                    'minheight' => self::IMAGEHEIGHT,
                    'minwidth'  => self::IMAGEWIDTH,
                    'maxheight' => self::IMAGEHEIGHT,
                    'maxwidth'  => self::IMAGEWIDTH,
                    'messages'  => array(
                        Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::HEIGHT_TOO_BIG =>
                            'The image must be exactly ' . self::IMAGEHEIGHT . ' pixels tall',
                        Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::HEIGHT_TOO_SMALL =>
                            'The image must be exactly ' . self::IMAGEHEIGHT . ' pixels tall',
                        Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::WIDTH_TOO_BIG =>
                            'The image must be exactly ' . self::IMAGEWIDTH . ' pixels wide',
                        Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::WIDTH_TOO_SMALL =>
                            'The image must be exactly ' . self::IMAGEWIDTH . ' pixels wide',
                        Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::NOT_DETECTED =>
                            'The image dimensions cannot be detected',
                        Zend_Validate_File_ImageSize::NOT_READABLE =>
                            'The image dimensions cannot be read'))))
        ));

        $this->addElement('multiCheckbox', 'Genres', array(
            'required'  => false,
            'label'     => 'Genres:',
            'attribs'   => array(
                'title'     => 'Please select the sites genres'
            ),
            'multiOptions'  => $genres,
            'filters' => array('int'),
            'validators' => array(
                array('NotEmpty', true, array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY =>
                            "You must select the sites genres",
                        Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::INVALID =>
                            "You must select the sites genres"))),
                array('InArray', true, array(
                    'haystack'  => array_keys($genres),
                    'messages' => array(
                        Zend_Validate_InArray::NOT_IN_ARRAY =>
                            "You must select the sites genres"))))
        ));

        $this->addElement('multiCheckbox', 'ArtworkMediums', array(
            'required'  => false,
            'label'     => 'Artwork Mediums:',
            'attribs'   => array(
                'title'     => 'Please select the sites artwork mediums'
            ),
            'multiOptions'  => $artworkMediums,
            'filters' => array('int'),
            'validators' => array(
                array('NotEmpty', true, array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY =>
                            "You must select the sites artwork mediums",
                        Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::INVALID =>
                            "You must select the sites artwork mediums"))),
                array('InArray', true, array(
                    'haystack'  => array_keys($artworkMediums),
                    'messages' => array(
                        Zend_Validate_InArray::NOT_IN_ARRAY =>
                            "You must select the sites artwork mediums"))))
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'save', array(
            'label' => 'Save',
            'attribs'   => array(
                'title' => 'Save')
        ));

        $this->addSubForm($directSitesDescription, 'DirectSitesDescription')
             ->addSubForm($directSitesTitle, 'DirectSitesTitle');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you but with one form only. As this post is a little old, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

All I can see is that your `'count'` validator looks a little wonky, it looks like you are requiring a minimum of 1 file at all times. As to why there is no error message, I have no idea.
Might try setting `'min' => 0`

```
array('count', true, array(
                'min'   => 1,
                'max'   => 1,
                'messages'  => array(
                    Zend_Validate_File_Count::TOO_FEW =>
                        'You must upload an image file',
                    Zend_Validate_File_Count::TOO_MANY =>
                        'You can only upload one image file'))),
```

Below is the API for Zend_Validate_File_Count constructor, see whole API at [ZF 1.11 API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/)

> __construct( integer|array|\Zend_Config $options ) : void Sets validator options
>
> Min limits the file count, when used with max=null it is the maximum
>   file count It also accepts an array with the keys 'min' and 'max' If
>   $options is a integer, it will be used as maximum file count As Array
>   is accepts the following keys: 'min': Minimum filecount 'max': Maximum
>   filecount Parameters Name Type    Description
>   $options  integer|array|\Zend_Config  Options for the adapter

Comment: Hi RockyFord, Thanks for your response.  I have tried setting min to zero as per your suggestion but with no luck, the validation still fails with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Double check to make sure that

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

is included in the html form element. I spent two hours with the same issue. Turns out that was my problem.

Comment: Hi Liz, thanks for your answer.  My forms enctype is correct (multipart/form-data)

Answer (score 0):

RockyFord is correct, you should set the `min` value of the `Count` validator to 0.

Even if an element is not required, its validators are still processed when the value is not empty.  File elements work a little different with the count validator.  If you specify a `min` greater than 0, it will still require that many files to be uploaded.

Try the following code where you turn off the required flag.  In addition, we will set the Count validator to require at least 0 files.

```
$form->getElement('image')
     ->setRequired(false)
     ->getValidator('count')
     ->setMin(0);
```

I tested this and it worked.  If I didn't set the min to 0, the form would fail validation, however, I would see an error message reading `You must upload an image file`.  Perhaps your decorators are not showing the error on File elements?

Comment: Hi drew010, thanks for your answer.  As I mentied above I have set the min to zero as per RockyFord's suggestion but I still get a validation error when I dont upload a file.  The getMessages() method of zend form returns an empty array so no errors are being reported internally.

Comment: Ok in that case, can you post more complete code for your form and controller where it is used?  Are you rendering form elements individually in your view?  If so maybe you left an element out?  Setting min to 0 should work.  Are you calling isValid in multiple places or did you validate an element by itself or maybe call `markAsError` or `addError` on the form or elements?

Comment: I have added some more code samples above showing the validation methods I use along with the forms themselves.  There are two forms which share one abstract class, one is set to required true on the file element so I expect the Admin_Form_AddDirectSite validation to fail which it does. Also if I remove all the validators from the file element the validation still fails.

Answer (score 0):

ZF 1.11
A much simpler solution is to remove the element upon submitting the form:

```
    $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
    $files  = $upload->getFileInfo();   

        if(empty($files))
        {
          $form->removeElement('image_name');
        }
        else
        {
          $form->image_name->receive();
        }

       if($form->isValid($_POST))
       {
         $formData = $form->getValues();
       }
```

Comment: But when running in validation errors your form is reloading without the file upload element, cause we removed it before rendering form.

Answer (score 0):

Override the method `isValid` inside the class deriving from `Zend_Form`.

```
/**
 * Class Custom_Form
 */
class Custom_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    // [...]

    /**
     * Validate the form
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @throws Zend_Form_Exception
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValid($data)
    {
        /** @var Zend_Form_Element_File $file */
        $file = $this->getElement('file');

        /**
         * Remember the validators we set before
         */
        $validators = $file->getValidators();

        /**
         * Remove validators if field is empty
         */
        if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
            $file->removeValidator('Extension');
        }

        /**
         * Run validation
         */
        $isValid = parent::isValid($data);

        /**
         * Set back the original validators after validation
         */
        $file->setValidators($validators);

        return $isValid;
    }

    // [...]
}
```